# Are my trees stressed?

Tags: indoors

I have 2 baby tamarind trees for almost 3 months. I am watering them only if the soil seems dry none the less. I have noticed that on the leaves they have some stains which is worrying. I don't know what to do.I normally keep them next to the window only if there are sunny days like today. Also i am thinking to feed them. I don't know if I should do that now. Can you please give me some tips or any advice.

Looking forward to your reply.

Kind regards,

Comment: Welcome! Judging what is going on and identifying a potential problem would be way easier with a photo or two accompanying the verbal description. Please take the [tour] and browse through the [help], especially [ask], to learn more about how the site works, then [edit] your post with more details.

Comment: How do I add a picture ?

Comment: Choose [edit]. There’s an image icon next to the formatting symbols. When you click on that, there’s a pop up window that leads you through the steps. Just make sure that the image size is 2MB max.